# How to transition from one VC contained in one VC, to a new VC which will be contained in the same VC as the other?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

When the app launches you begin on the ViewController (the one in the middle). From there I add the VC on the right. When a user taps a button which is on this VC I want that view to go away (which I currently accomplish by just changing its frame to 900) and in its place comes the VC on the Left.

*All the things I have tried failed given that I am so unclear on how to do this.*

**How do I make this kind of functionality work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
        if let ViewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {        
            //here...   
        } else if let viewcontroller = segue.destination as? ViewController1 {
            //here..
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have reference to the container view you can hide and unhide Views but the `RightViewController` on the right must communicate to the main middle `MiddleViewController`

Here you can use `Protocols` to communicate between the two, have a look into https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5 for more details.

When the `RightViewController` tells/delegates the `MiddleViewController` that the button is tapped

you can just

```
self.rightContainerView.isHidden = true
self.leftContainerView.isHidden = left
```